# Python: how to Add DictReader row as dictionary to list with an update

Tags: python, dictionary

My code basically just goes thru checking each row of a DictReader (a list of dicts) and puts duplicates in the RejectedEvents list of dicts and returns result, which is a deduplicated dict of dicts. I also need to add a reason to each row of RejectedEvents because I will later be rejecting for other reasons as well. The code is pretty self explanatory as is the problem, but not the solution; The issue is the line marked #PROBLEM, and the problem disappears when I take out the update statement; with the update statement, null is assigned and without it row is assigned, so the update is messing it up.

```
def GetScrubbedEventData(MetricID, EventsRaw, RejectEvents):
    start = time.time()
    pass_count = 0
    fail_count = 0

    result = {}
    for row in csv.DictReader(EventsRaw, delimiter=","):
        try:
            #check duplicate
            result[row['AssetID']]
            Reason = {"RejectedFor": "Duplicate AssetID in same file."}
            RejectEvents.append(dict(row).update(Reason)) #PROBLEM
            fail_count += 1
        except KeyError:
            row['EventStart'] = scrub.Date(row['EventStart'])
            row['EventEnd'] = scrub.Date(row['EventEnd'])
            result[row['AssetID']] = row
            pass_count += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the row and then append the updated row, not the return value of `.update` which is `None`:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(EventsRaw):
    ...
    row.update(Reason)
    RejectEvents.append(row)
```

Or you can set a new directly on dict `row` without having to create the single-valued dict `Reason`:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(EventsRaw):
    ...
    row["RejectedFor"] = "Duplicate AssetID in same file."
    RejectEvents.append(row)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks... I could have sworn I tried that and thought it failed because I was updating a row from DictRead and not a dict... After testing, the first solution fails when I was using dict(row).update(Reason).... but take out dict() and it works... Thanks.

Comment: The `dict` call does not work because it updates a new unreferenced dict instead of `row`.